# Very slow wi-fi on Intel wireless 3165

Tags: wireless

i'm on ubuntu 16.04. Wired connection works perfectly, but wi-fi connection is extremely slow. any ideas?`*-network

       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 79
       serial: 08:d4:0c:be:a8:52
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.5.0-040500-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:279 memory:d5100000-d5101fff`
i'm on 4.5 kernel

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Finally, I suggest that you install the latest firmware:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working correctly.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful to you, please accept it. http://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working!