# RTL8188EE wireless card not functioning properly

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my ASUS laptop.  I previously had Windows 10 on the system.  With Windows 10, the Wi-Fi capabilities worked flawlessly, but when I installed Ubuntu I began having Wi-Fi issues.  I can connect to most Wi-Fi networks successfully.  However, it seems that if there is any traffic on the network at all, my connection is so slow that most websites won't load.  The only wireless network that I can use consistently is my home network, on which I am the only user.  Also, I have to be within 20 or 30 feet of my home router for the connection to work on Ubuntu.  On the other hand, when I had Windows 10 I could browse the internet consistently in my bedroom, which is about 60 feet away from the router.

Since I had no Wi-Fi trouble with Windows 10, do you think this issue could be caused by the driver installed on Ubuntu?  I have not tampered with the driver, so the one that Ubuntu installed automatically is still on the system.  I ran the [wireless-info](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) program to aid in troubleshooting, and I posted the results here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17336238/.  Apparently I have a Realtek RTL8188EE wireless adapter, and the driver running is specific for that adapter.

Comment: See [chili555's](http://askubuntu.com/a/786430/300665) answer.  I think everything but the firmware is relevant

Answer (score 0):

Windows offers automatic switching between Access Points and channels to find the best connection. Ubuntu comes with GNOME Network Manager that does not offer this fuctionality.

This will cause problems if you use your laptop in a congested enviroment.
To solve this you need to get your computer to do the hard work through a script such as getwifi .